# Remove Slack symbol from top panel possible?

Tags: 20.04, globalmenu, slack

I have Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop and when I have Slack running, the symbol is shown in the top panel, see here:

[image]

I don't like the symbol when the app is running, how I can remove it?

Please note that I want to continue using the Slack app!

**EDIT:** This is what I get when I go to the website https://extensions.gnome.org/local/: [image]

Comment: Hi heynnema, thank you, I will give it a try asap, it might just take some days before I get to it. :-)

Comment: Two clicks, and 5 seconds, and it's installed. Another minute to adjust the prefs/settings. Go for it. Report back.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, it took me really long to finally get to it ... Unfortunately, I don't really know how to install the program. So I went to the page you linked in your answer, downloaded version 3.6, with extension 24, and I get a zip file that I have extracted as well. But how do I proceed from here?

Comment: I updated my answer to include simple installation instructions...

Comment: Ah, so you have it as a browser extension? I cannot see the on/off switch anywhere ...

Comment: It's a GNOME Shell extension. Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and follow the on-screen instructions to install two pieces of software to enable GNOME Shell extension management, then you can follow my answer.

Comment: I edited my message, to show you what my screen returns.

Comment: As I mentioned, "follow the on-screen instructions" to install two pieces of software to make this all work.

Comment: Okay: I installed the browser extension for Firefox, but I don't know how to activate the native host connector ... :-( The documentation is not really helpful to me, I am afraid.

Comment: Good. Now click on the "Wiki page" link and it'll tell you the simple command to install the native host connector. (I think it's something like "sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell"... but check me on that). Then you can do my answer.

Comment: Yes, it is "sudo apt-get install chrome-gnome-shell", but I thought this is only for Chrome!?

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Please don't take this personally, but I haven't managed to install the icon-hider, and by now, I'm afraid there is no reason for me to do so. I'm sorry to have to tell you. :-( I know you were very polite, but I just didn't get it. I will not pursue this any further, if you want, and that's why I'm not gonna upvote or accept your answer, you can downvote mine, if you want. All the best to you, and thanks a lot for having tried! But as I wrote, I won't pursue this any further, sorry.

Comment: No problem. I hope you found a solution that works for you.